# php- curl isn't working

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code, I have two cURL statements in the same program. The first one uses $ch and second uses $ch1.  The problem is first one is getting executed and showing the output but second one does nothing.

```
<?php
include ('DBconnect.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$verified = "1";
$error = array();
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $error[] = 'I am sure you have a name!';
}
else {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}

if (empty($_POST['phone'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please enter your phone number with country code';
}
else {
    $Phone = $_POST['phone'];
}

if (empty($_POST['Password'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please choose a password ';
}
else {
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
}

if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '
{ // If everything's OK...

    // Make sure the phone number is available:

    $query_verify_phone = "SELECT * FROM members  WHERE Phone ='$Phone'";
    $result_verify_phone = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_phone);
    if (!$result_verify_phone) { //if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_phone==false)
        echo ' Database Error Occured ';
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_phone) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this phone number.
        $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `members` ( `Name`, `Phone`, `Password`, `Verified`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Phone', '$Password', '$verified')";
        $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
        if (!$result_insert_user) {
            echo 'Query Failed ';
        }

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.
            $customerToken = "TOKEN HERE";
            $clientTransactionId = rand(55555, 77777);
            $duration = "180";
            $countryCode = "91";
            $z2vToken = "TOKEN HERE";
            $postData = array(
                'customerToken' => $customerToken,
                'clientTransactionId' => $clientTransactionId,
                'callerid' => $Phone,
                'duration' => $duration,
                'countryCode' => $countryCode,
                'z2vToken' => $z2vToken,
            );

            // create post body

            $post_body = '';
            foreach($postData as $key => $value) {
                $post_body.= urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
            }

            $post_body = rtrim($post_body, '&');

            // Initialize CURL data to send via POST to the API
            // FIRST ONE CURL REQUEST- WORKING

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.zipdial.com/z2v/startTransaction.action");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_body);

            // Execute CURL command and return into variable ch

            $string = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $json = json_decode($string);

            // now the json has been decoded
            // echo "Please do a missed call  on: ";
            // echo "<img src=' ".$json->img."'>";

            $pf = 'fl' . uniqid();
            $un = uniqid($pf);
            $fpl = 'img' . $un . '.png';
            file_put_contents($fpl, file_get_contents($json->img));
```

Everything above goes fine but the second curl request is not working:

```
            // EVERYTHING ABOVE GOES FINE. BELOW IS SECOND REQUEST- NOT WORKING

            $url = "https://api.idolondemand.com/1/api/sync/ocrdocument/v1";
            $post = array(
                'apikey' => "MY KEY HERE",
                'url' => "http://site.ext/users/$fpl",
                'mode' => "document_photo"
            );
            $ch1 = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $ocr = curl_exec($ch1);
            $jsonocr = json_decode($ocr, true);
            $textblock = $jsonocr['text'][0];
            echo '<div class="success">Please give a missed call to ' . $textblock['text'] . ' from your registered phone number to activate account. </div>';
            curl_close($ch1);
        }
        else { // If it did not run OK.
            echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system  error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</div>';
        }
    }
    else { // The phone number is not available.
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That phone number has already been registered. </div>';
    }
}
else { //If the "error" array contains error msg , display them
    echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
    foreach($error as $key => $values) {
        echo ' <li>' . $values . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ol></div>';
}

mysqli_close($dbc); //Close the DB Connection
} // End of the main Submit conditional.

?>
```

I can  make request to second curl request manually from my browser and it works but it isn't working here. What's wrong?

Comment: @Alrazah When I make rrquest from browser, it shows success message in json but in php it isnt getting executed with no success or error messages at all .

Comment: PLease reduce that code to what is relevant here. Thanks.

Comment: you have error_reporting activated in your php? `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @Alrazah yes but still no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get this error when you dump `curl_error($ch1)` :

```
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.idolondemand.com
```

You can add this line when you curl https if you have no sensitive transiting data :

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Here is the code which works for me :

```
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
$ocr = curl_exec($ch1);
var_dump($ocr);
var_dump(curl_error($ch1));
```

When I do this, I get :

```
string(97) "{ "message": "Unknown API key", "detail": { "error": 2002, "key": "MY KEY HERE" } }" string(0) ""
```

Comment: And what do you get when you dump `curl_error($ch1)` ? That's weird because when I add this line, it works for me with your site.

Comment: I did var_dump ($ch1) and it gave: bool(false)

Comment: on curl_error it gave unknown ssl error. i have added the curl option you said after SETOPT_URL

Comment: I edited my answer to show you where I put the SSL handling line. What's the exact error you get on `curl_error` ?

Comment: I just tried your code and that too gave me: bool(false) string(69) "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.idolondemand.com:443 "

Comment: I edited my answer again by adding another ssl handling line... can you try it ? I also noticed that I made a typo and used `$ch` variable instead of `$ch1`

Comment: Tried, still same error. Also tried changing ssl version to 3 in setopt. its possible that my server has some ssl problems? i dont have ssl installed.

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps you can install ssl on your server. However, be careful when you use this ssl options because it will ignore ssl verifications that protect your transiting data. I mentionned it in my answer.

Comment: I have set VERIFYPEER to false and VERIFYHOST to 1 and it worked.:)

Answer (score 0):

I have set VERIFYPEER to false and VERIFYHOST to 1 and it worked.